# Are these Haikus More or Less related?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> As the cloudless sky
>   Hues the days are bounded by
>   Ball of fire knows why
>
> Warning and Alarm
>   Envious of others' charm
>   Cold enough to harm

The correct answer should be seven(7) letters and an explanation.

Comment: I think you're too much in the rhyming spirit to be writing haiku puzzles, Chowzen! They're well written poems regardless! :D

Comment: @El-Guest Thanks! I know that haiku don't usually rhyme, but there's no law against it, right?

Comment: Just checked...[you're good!](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/rules-for-writing-haiku.html) Rhyming is uncommon but not forbidden -- I learned something new! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

> I think the first one is a rainbow, which could to either **rainbow** or **roygbiv** which is the first letters of all the colours.

Explanation:

> Rainbows are in the sky, have many hues and are made by the sun(a ball of fire).

Comment: +1 Not what I was looking for, but good enough for me to accept if nobody has gets what I was going for in the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: There's a hint in the title

Comment: probably someone with a last name biv.

Comment: What is the actual answer? this post is old and I just wanna know.

Comment: The answers to each line were (1fg) Plna, Zntragn, Lryybj (Oynpx) / (2aq) Erq, Terra, Oyhr—(PZLX/ETO). Gur gvgyr'f "Zber be Yrff" vaqvpngrf [Nqqvgvir naq Fhogenpgvir Pbybe Zrgubqf](http://www.worqx.com/color/color_systems.htm)